# C++ classes vs. C different files

Tags: c++, c, class

Currently in a project there is a clear set of functions that pertain to a clear responsibility. Because the responsibility is a periodic process that requires buffers and counters for each iteration, I have to reset the variables used by those functions after each cycle. The variables are mostly static because per cycle the functions are called thousands of times. (It is a set of digital FIR filters that process the 5 second data that is coming in every 2 minutes or so). The variables have to be declared in the file scope, because the functions share them. E.g. the reset / initialize function and the actual filter functions.

As of now, the whole project is in C (but C++ is easily supported, as the possibly breaking parts already contain 'extern C {}'). To make the code cleaner, I thought to group the functions and variables in a separate implementation file. But of course, I could also use C++ classes, which I would like to work with more.

What are the essential differences between these options?

**Simplified example of what I mean:**
In this example, I just kept the structure of the program. The Filter() function is called for example 1000 times in 5 seconds for the first iteration. Then for the next iterations, the Reset() function is called prior to the actual Filter() function calls, to reset all the buffers that are used.

```
// File-scope variables
static float   buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
static uint8_t bufferOffset = 0;

// Filter
static float Filter (const float sample)
{
  buffer[bufferOffset] = sample;

  // Removed actual filter code here

  return result;
}

// Reset functions
static void Reset (void)
{
  memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
  bufferOffset = 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to show the code you're talking about, it's hard to answer this in the abstract.

Comment: This question is way to broad. Whether or not a class it the right approach depends on the type of variables and what they describe, and what the functions are about. C++ supports free function and namespaces so that you don't need to force code into a oop class structure when it is not really needed.

Comment: I have added a small snippet to better illustrate what I mean. I personally don't feel like the question is too broad, I'm trying to better understand what the functional differences and design choices are between implementing my set of functions and their variables in a class vs. in a separate C file implementation. Many of these variables should only be adjusted by their own function, or by the Reset() function. Not by others. Thus, a class would be a nice way, but not the only way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To declare `static` file scope variables is the simplest form of private encapsulation. Such design is particularly common in embedded systems and hardware-related code. It's perfectly OK practice in a single-threaded program where there is just one single instance of the module/ADT that uses the variables ("singleton pattern").

Given your simple example, this should be just fine for your specific case. The art of program design is to know when to add extra layers of abstraction and when to avoid them. It isn't easy to teach, this mostly comes with experience.

A rule of thumb for the inexperienced programmer: if you are uncertain how to make the code more abstract, then *don't* add that extra abstraction. It is very likely to cause more far harm than it does good.

---

In case the code turns more complex, the next level of abstraction is simply to split it into several related files. Or rather into several .h + .c file pairs.

The point where this turns burdensome is where you need multiple instances of the module doing the same thing. Suppose you need multiple filters using the same code, but getting called by unrelated caller code. Having one set of `static` variables won't work then.

The sloppy but old school way of taking such abstraction further in C is to make a struct definition visible to the caller, then provide an interface such as `void fir_init (fir_t* obj);` where `obj` is allocated on the caller-side. This solves the multiple instances problem, but breaks private encapsulation.

The professional design would rather be to use the concept of *opaque types* (which is explained in multiple posts elsewhere on this site), where you only expose an incomplete struct type to the caller and let your module handle the allocation. This gives true OO design - you can declare multiple instances of the object while maintaining private encapsulation.

---

The C++ equivalent of opaque type is `class` and abstract base classes behave in exactly the same manner as opaque types in C - the caller can declare a pointer/reference to one, but not declare an object. C++ also provides constructors/destructors, which is more convenient than calling some "init" function manually. But this also leads to execution overhead when static storage duration objects have their default constructors called at start-up.

Also, C++ member functions come with their `this` pointer, so you don't need to pass a pointer to the object along manually. You can also have `static` members in a class and they behave just like C file scope `static`, with a single instance shared between all instances.

Comment: The biggest down-side of C culture is that C programmers tend to avoid having any form of design but just aimlessly "code away". And the biggest down-side of C++ culture is that C++ programmers tend to add far too much of needless abstraction, obfuscation and meta programming. Both of these extremes are very harmful. So it's good to study both languages, or at least to study OO design. Then find a good middle ground, where you stick to OO, but without using various more or less worthless C++ bloat features. C++ is far too complex for its own good, and you can do without a lot of its features.

Answer (score 3):

The usual approach in C to avoid those shared states is to define a structure encapsulating all the relevant state, pass it to every function and operate solely on it.

**Example:**

```
// buffer.h
#pragma once

// opaque data structure whose content
// isn't available to the outside
struct buffer;

// but you may allocate and free such a data structure
struct buffer *alloc_buffer();
void free_buffer(struct buffer *b);

// and you may operate on it with the following functions
float filter_buffer(struct buffer *b);
void reset_buffer(struct buffer *b);
void add_to_buffer(struct buffer *b, const float *data, size_t size);
```

And the source looks like this:

```
// buffer.c
#include "buffer.h"

struct buffer {
    float content[BUFFER_SIZE];
    uint8_t offset;
}

struct buffer *alloc_buffer() {
    return malloc(sizeof(struct buffer));
}

void free_buffer(struct buffer *b) {
    free(b);
}

float filter_buffer(struct buffer *b) {
    // work with b->content and b->offset instead
    // on global buffer and bufferOffset
    return result;
}

void reset_buffer(struct buffer *b) {
    memset(b->content, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
    b->offset = 0;
}

void add_to_buffer(struct buffer *b, const float *data, size_t num) {
    memcpy(b->content + b->offset, data, sizeof(float) * num);
    b->offset += num;
}
```

Thus you avoid a global state which for example dramatically simplifies multi-threaded applications of your code. And since you return an opaque data structure, you avoid leaking information about the internal structure of your buffer.

Now you may use this data structure in a different source file:

```
#include "buffer.h"

int main() {
    struct buffer *const b = alloc_buffer();

    // b->content[0] = 1; // <-- error, buffer is an opaque data type and
                          //     you may only use the functions declared in
                          //     buffer.h to access and modify it

    const float data[2] = { 3.1415926, 2.71828 }
    add_to_buffer(b, data, sizeof(data) / sizeof(data[0]));
    const float result = filter_buffer(b);

    return 0;
}
```

**To answer you question:** Even though you could separate your functions and global state even further into several compilation units, in the end you still have a shared global state. Except in some special cases I consider this a code smell.

The above described solution more or less corresponds to a C++ solution. You define a class encapsulating some state and methods operating on it. All instantiated objects are independent from each other.

Comment: Yep this is good design, this is exactly how you implement "opaque type" that I mentioned in my own answer.